# Generating random number until they repeat in C/CPP

Tags: c++, c, random

I have a problem with a program in C or CPP. I need to make a program that will generate a random nubers in range of 1-365, but when the program generates the same number as it allredy did, the program will write the count of numbers and repeat it self again 100 times.

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <time.h>

int main()
{
    int lower = 1, upper = 365, count = 365;

    srand(time(0));

    printf("The random numbers are: ");
    for (int i = 0; i < count; i++) {
            
        int num = (rand() % (upper - lower + 1)) + lower;
        printf("%d ", num);
    }

    return 0;
}
```

I know how to make the generator for random numbers but i have problem with stopping it when the numbers reapeat.

Comment: Do not tag both C and C++ except when asking about differences or interactions between the two languages. Pick one and delete the other tag.

Comment: Since the valid range of numbers is 1 to 365, a simple boolean array, `bool seen[366] = {};`, can be used solve the problem of whether or not a number has already been seen

Comment: Are you trying to understand the birthday paradox?

Comment: You probably need an array with 365 elements set to zero — call it `int seen[365] = { 0 };`.  As you generate the numbers, you (a) count them and (b) check to see whether the number has been seen before: `if (seen[number]++ != 0) { …it has been seen before…time to stop and process it… }`.  Wrap it all in a function so you can call the function 100 times.

Comment: Is the following the goal of your program? Repeat this 100 times: Generate random numbers from 1 to 365, inclusive, until a number is repeated, and write to standard output the number of numbers generated. And then your question is “How do I write code to detect the first time a randomly generated number is a duplicate of a previously generated number?”

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Based on what you want to do, this (not tested) code could give you into the right way:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <time.h>

int main()
{
    // declare the lower and upper limits of the rand numbers
    int lower = 1, upper = 365;

    // number of repetitions of the process. 
    // this will repeat the same process 100 times.
    int count = 100;

    // set the random seed
    srand(time(0));

    // loop for the repetition of the process
    for (int x = 0; x < count; x++) {
      // value to count the quantity of random numbers of this execution
      int sum = 0;

      // flag to break the 'while' loop
      bool canContinue = true;

      // array of booleans. 365 because you have random numbers between 1 - 365
      // when a random numbers is generated, the array in that position will be set to true
      // when another random number is generated we check if the position of his value is true
      // to validate is that number is already set. 
      bool numbers[365] = {};

      // loop generates random numbers until a repeat number is found
      while (canContinue) {
        // retrieve a random number
        int num = (rand() % (upper - lower + 1)) + lower;

        // validate if the generated number position is already taken
        if (numbers[num - 1] != true) {
          // set position of array taken. num - 1 because positions in arrays start from 0
          numbers[num - 1] = true;
          // count +1 new random number not repeated of this exectution
          sum++;
        } else {
          // the position of the random number is taken, means is a repeated number
          canContinue = false;
        }
      }
      // print the result of this loop and countinue until we have 100 repetitions of the process
      printf("step %d: %d", x + 1, sum);
    }
    return 0;
}
```

In order to detect a random number is repeated, my approach was have an array of bools projecting that each number has an available position. [false, false... until 365 positions].

When a number is generated his position will be true (position = generated number - 1). In case the first number is 2 the array will have a representation like this: [false, true, false , false, ....and the others falses values].

When other number is generated we check his position, in the case of the repetition of number 2 the result of the array[2 - 1] will be true and I inmediatilly conclude the loop.

Comment: Code without explanation is not a good answer.